# Intercept and update href on click

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a

```
<a id="btn" href="http://google.com">Link</a>
```

I want to intercept the click and temporarily change the event href to "http://google.com?linkClicked=true"

But only for that brief moment, when I inspect the source code again the href should stay the same.

So far I've tried

```
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    this.href = 'http://google.com?linkClicked=true'
    return true
})
```

But this changes the href permanently! I tried setting the href of the event but nothing.

Comment: have you tried using `setTimeout` to reset it?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I tend to stay away from setTimeouts but that is actually a smart idea! Just a timeout with 0 delay will allow for the function to return before it is executed

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this change? By the time the link is clicked and the event goes through, the browser locks in the link as clicked. Are you trying to do something to the referer info on the receiving site?

Comment: @Nermin what's your goal? like "hide" the real href you will be redirected? because you can just use `location.href` using JS without editing the href of the anchor tag

Comment: The goal is to hide the real href from scrapers and crawlers that just look at the source code href, meanwhile real users actually click on the link

Comment: Most scrapers don't even run a page's JavaScript, so your change will have limited returns if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: @volt what do u mean? It's precisely for that reason that I don't want the real url exposed in the html source code

Comment: @Nermin, you want to make two changes. First, as soon as you click, you change the URL for scrappers. Then you change it back to normal for regular users immediately, correct? I'm saying almost all scrappers won't execute the first change. They don't run JavaScript. They copy the HTML as a string in most cases.

Comment: @volt no, I change the url for users. The default url is for scrapers

Comment: @Nermin Then you have nothing to worry about. Your code as is in the question should be more than enough. You don't need to reset the href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the property of the link. Cancel the action by calling `preventDefault()` on the event, then initiate your own navigation.

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = 'http://google.com?q=Hello';
})
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="http://google.com">Link</a>
```

I should add that going somewhere else than is originally displayed is suspicious and not user-friendly. It will also not work for users that use the context-menu to open a link in a new tab and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the user wants to open the link in a new tab?

Comment: Then you should use the actual correct url in the first place. Trying to change the url on the go after the user has decided to go there is really suspicious. I can't think of any other use for this except fraud. Maybe explain your actual intention to receive better recommendations.

Comment: I am simply adding a query parameter to know that its a real user. But nvm I found that `window.open(url, '_blank')` did the trick ;)

Comment: This will not work if the user themselves right-click and choose "open in new tab"... I'd suggest replacing the actual urls via javascript while the page is already loading.